# Changing a JQuery UI tab name does not work with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

In Both Firefox and Chrome, I can dynamically change the text on a JQuery UI tab with:

```
$('#tabs ul:first li:eq(' + tabNumber + ') a').append(" ( " + counter + " )");
```

However, this is not working with Internet Explorer 9. The .append() function is not the culprit, it seems to be that IE cannot find `'#tabs ul:first li:eq(' + tabNumber + ') a'`.

Does anyone know of a possible fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just set up a jsfiddle, and it worked. I then traced the problem down to where I set the tabNumber. IE debugging tells me that tabNumber is NaN (not a number). Here is where I declare it: var tabNumber = tabId[tabId.length - 1] - 1;

Comment: What I'm trying to do with the above statement is parse a number out of a string: "tabs-4", and then subtract one from that number.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by setting tabNumber as

```
var tabNumber = tabId.charAt( tabId.length-1 ) - 1;
```

instead of

```
var tabNumber = tabId[tabId.length - 1] - 1;
```

The latter does not seem to work with IE.